# C# WPF.Net Core cannot Close window from other thread

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently I'm working on the WPF on .net core.
My application have to start Cef core to run the UI (instead of using WPF form).
Before of that I want to display a simple WPF window that say "Loading..."
So in the application start up, I have to start a thread like this

```
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                DisplayLoader = true;
                var f = new Loading();
                f.Loaded += (a, b) =>
                {
                    Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        while (DisplayLoader)
                            Thread.Sleep(250);
                        f.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                        {
                            f.Close();
                        });
                        f.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(delegate ()
                        {
                            f.Close();
                        }));
                    });
                };
                f.Show();
                Dispatcher.Run();
            }
            catch
            {
                Loader.Close();
            }
        });
```

The point is, when the DisplayLoader become false, I saw the Dispatcher invoke the Close function too, however, nothing happened. I already follow a lot of answer on stackOverflow, but none of them works.

Below the thread start is this function, It will invoke Cef and display a Cef Window

```
        thread.Start();
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        CefApp
           .Run(assembly)
```

When the CefApp Loaded, the DisplayLoader will be set to false.

```
        protected override void OnLoadEnd(CefBrowser browser, CefFrame frame, int httpStatusCode)
        {
            base.OnLoadEnd(browser, frame, httpStatusCode);
            if (frame.IsValid)
            {
                if (App.DisplayLoader)
                {
                    App.DisplayLoader = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:** 
The problem actually come from the CefAppBuilder, it embedded C++ code from CefGlue, then may cause some issue with C# function. Just do not modify any C# variable in C invoke function then it's fine.

Comment: I really do believe, you'd be _much_ better off with an `async Task`. Have you ever dealt with Taskbased Async?

Comment: How do you start the thread and how do you set `DisplayLoader`? Your issue is not reproducible based on the code you have posted.

Comment: Luckily my app is actually open source: https://github.com/daricvn/bdo_translator
If you want to re-produce the issue just clone the code.
TranslatorApp.cs is where the DisplayLoader become false (it'll always run after the Loading start no matter what due to the slowness of Cef)

Answer (score 1):

The thread that executes a `Window` must be a UI thread which must be a STA thread.

You have to mark the thread as STA using `Thread.SetApartmentState`:

**App.xaml**

```
private void Run(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  Thread uiThread = new Thread(DoWork);
  uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
  uiThread.IsBackground = true;
  uiThread.Start();
}
```

---

But my recommended approach is to execute the initialization asynchronously. This avoids the overhead of creating additional UI threads and is also more compact in terms of lines of code and readability:

**App.xaml**

```
private TaskCompletionSource TaskCompletionSource { get; set; }

private async void Run(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
  Window splashScreen = new SplashScreenWindow();
  splashScreen.Show();

  await InitializeCefAppAsync();
  splashScreen.Close();
}

private async Task InitializeCefAppAsync()
{
  this.TaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

  var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
  CefApp.Loaded += OnCefAppLoaded;

  // Consider to implement an awaitable CefApp.InitializeAsync method 
  // instead of calling Run directly. This way you can remove the TaskCompletionSource pattern
  CefApp.Run(assembly); 

  return this.TaskCompletionSource.Task;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
}
```